# knitr_child throws error after upgrade to R 3.0

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

A script that has been running seamlessly for over a month stopped adding my child Latex code into my main document following an upgrade to R 3.0.1. The following snippet used to include the text from the compiled test.rnw file in my main document (so that it could be compiled as one document). Now it just includes the filenames of the compiled rnw files.

```
<<run-all, include=FALSE>>=
    out = NULL
    for (i in 1:10) {
      out = c(out, knit_child('test.rnw', sprintf('test-template-%d.tex', i)))
    }
@

\Sexpr{paste(out, collapse = '\n')}
```

When I try to run the knit_child command interactively, I get this error:

```
> knit_child('test.rnw', sprintf('test-template-%d.tex', i))
Error in setwd(opts_knit$get("output.dir")) : character argument expected
```

Running knit() alone will compile the Latex code, if I then run knin_child() there is not error but the "out" object just contains the filename of the child file instead of the contents.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `knit_child()` interactively. It was designed to be called *inside* `knit()`.

As you have noted, `knit_child()` in the latest version of `knitr` returns the content of the child document if you do not provide the second argument. By explicitly providing the second argument `sprintf('test-template-%d.tex', i)`, you mean "please write the output to this file and return the filename".

To fix the problem, you need to remove the second argument:

```
<<run-all, include=FALSE>>=
    out = NULL
    for (i in 1:10) {
      out = c(out, knit_child('test.rnw'))
    }
@

\Sexpr{paste(out, collapse = '\n')}
```

Comment: According to the help file, the dots arguments in knit_child() are to be passed to knit(), implying that knit() is called within knit_child(). The error is not my main issue. The fact that knit_child() is not behaving as it was before (it returns the file names and not the file contents when I compile a .Rnw document) is my problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: In case I was not clear before -- the child documents are being created correctly by knit_child() and named according to the second argument (so that at least seems to be working), the file contents are just not returned.

Comment: @midden sorry perhaps I was unclear - you should not provide the output filename if you want the file content, and I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks Yihui. Maybe your example at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_expand.html should be updated to reflect this? The last chunk triggers the error in question.

Comment: @YihuiXie I am receiving the same error but simpler code straight out of the book. `intro <- knitr::knit_child("NSQIP_Intro_text.Rmd" ,  quiet = TRUE  )
cat(intro, sep = '\n')` ... This was working earlier today but started throwing errors. I have specified `setwd()` above.